# How to properly prepare a beef escalope (from the topside)?

Tags: meat, slow-cooking

I've read a number of recipes that call for different cooking times, so I'm a bit baffled.

Normally, the escalopes are cuts from the topside (that's the bottom) of a cow. These are then hammered with a mallet, salt & peppered, passed through flour and sautéed. A pan-sauce is made from the fond and the escalopes are added back in.

The question is: How long?
I've read times ranging from 15' to two hours...

Does it depend on the age of the animal? Or the race? Is there any objective way to determine when it's properly cooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topside is quite a tough cut, so I'd tend towards a longer cooking time; as 'low and slow' as possible, really. With other meats, escalopes are usually made using leaner cuts, like chicken breast or pork tenderloin, which would be cooked relatively quickly, so I'm surprised your recipes call for topside.

Comment: Maybe something got 'lost in translation'... (thanks for the edit)